# Facebook Comments box plugin automatically changed width

Tags: html, css, facebook

As you can see on the "Guestbook" component of the website, the width of the Facebook plug-in within the div has changed abruptly. Another strange error I had was that it worked in MAMP then it didn't(the same time it automatically adjusted the width.

Is there any reason as to why this is happening/any way to fix it? I would adjust overflow but that needs to stay at scroll because it needs to be the same width of the DIV.

Comment: need more explanation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframes **margin-left** causes the issue

See the image

[image]

So add

```
iframe
{
margin-left:0px !important;
}
```